how to connect to computers in the LAN of the server?
I would like to can connect from a client to computers in the LAN of the OpenVpn Server.
I have read this question, and really it is my problem, but the solution it is configure the router, I would like to configure the OpenVpn server.
For that, I am following the documentation.
Also I am following this tutorial.
But I am not able to cofigure the VPN to can connect to the computers in the LAN of the server.
The server is a Windows 11 computer and I am using the WinTun adapter.
The VPN is 10.20.0.0 255.255.255.0 and the server is 10.20.0.1. The lan of the server is 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 and the server has the IP 192.168.1.2.
I am following this steps:

I enable IPEnableRouter in the server, editing the register.
I add a new route in the server computer: route add -p 10.20.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.2
I add the push in the server openVpn configuration file: push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"

With that, it seems it is enough, but I can connect.
Is it needed to do something more?
Thanks.

I add a new route in the server computer: route add -p 10.20.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.2 The route makes no sense on the server. Where you need it is the other LAN hosts. (If that's not feasible, at least have it on the LAN gateway. Or else you'll need to set up NAT on the server for the VPN clients.)

Thanks. It is true, it has to be added in the gateway, that normally is the router. If I added the route in the router, it works. So the question that I read is correct when it solves the problem adding the route in the router instead of the computer that runs OpenVPN.
